# AngularJs load all files before initialization

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having the nomod Module not available error.

Now my situation is that during development, my files may be loaded in random order (due using the grunt tool [injector](https://github.com/klei/grunt-injector)). So I may declare the module in `foo.module.js` and the implementation in `foo.js`. I may be loading `foo.js` first.

foo.js

```
angular.module('Foo').config( //...
```

foo.module.js

```
angular.module('Foo', [
  'ngRoute'
  // etc....
]);
```

A simplified version of my html page would be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app-wrapper" class="app" ng-view></div>

    <!-- [injector:js] -->
    <script src="/app/foo.js"></script>
    <script src="/app/foo.module.js"></script>
    <!-- [endinjector] -->

  <script>
    angular.element(document).ready(function() {
      angular.bootstrap(document, ["Foo"]);
    });
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note the `[injector:js]` tag. This tool will scan the source directory and add references of all javascript files found between this tag. The other process of the build will take these files, concat and minify them (whose tags are left out from this example).

So if I run this in dev environment (the html as it is now) or after build (concat + minification)...i'll end up with the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'Foo' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument
```

Is there any way to prevent angular from executing the methods that depends on the module before they actually load? I cannot re-arrange the order. I cannot use require.js or any AMD either as this is already tied into the build tool.

Comment: could you create a plnkr for it? It seems you should define module like angular.module('Foo', [...]) before loading foo.js

Comment: I clean solution is to always declare one module per file.

Comment: @Phil how would that work when I may have 10s of files, possibly hundreds that are essentially 1 module? The main module file would be very large.

Comment: @ShawnMclean concatentation and minification (through your favorite build process, like Maven or Gulp) solves the issue of turning hundreds of files into a few files.

Comment: @Hylianpuffball but thats what I'm doing now. I'm using grunt injector to automatically scan my directory and add the references. But it does it in alphabetical order based on directory and file name. Then I use other concat and minification process after. My problem lies where I add the references, when they are not in order, it gives that error. My concern with Phil's suggestion is the maintenance of the main module file to keep track of all modules if I have 1 per file.

Comment: @ShawnMclean Have you tried switching the order, where you do concatenation and minification first, and then use grunt injector on the generated files?

Comment: From memory, there's some plugins (maybe grunt, maybe gulp) that can work out the module order. I'll have a look around

Comment: You could use grunt.registerTask('build', [...]) to specify the orders

Comment: Ah, it was a gulp plugin ~ https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-angular-filesort

Comment: @Phil thats exactly what I'm looking for...Now to figure out how to get this to run from grunt. Thanks!

Comment: @ShawnMclean internally it uses [ng-dependencies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-dependencies) which appears to be build-tool agnostic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically I use a combination of the [usemin grunt plugin](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin) with [include-source](https://github.com/jwvdiermen/grunt-include-source).

This allows me to pull my module file out from the automatic includes, but still have it bundled, annotated, and minified.

The `index.html` ends up looking something like this:

```
<!-- build:js js/app.js -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<!-- include: "type": "js", "files": "js/controllers/**/*.js" -->
<script src="js/controllers/someController.js"></script>
...
... lots of scripts here ...
...
<!-- /include -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

It's worth looking at for your purposes.